# how to quit matlab gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface, quit

I have this callback in my matlab gui that is executed by the menu->Programm->quit.

However the handles is empty.

```
function menuProgramQuit_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to menuProgramQuit (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
close(handles.figure1);
```

Therefore I would like to know how to quit a matlab gui, or why in my code the handles struct is empty?

Comment: make sure all your GUI callbacks saves `handles` when they terminate.

Comment: What do you mean by `saves handles` ?

Comment: Using `guidata` : http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html

Answer (score 1):

You've almost got it. Try this ([Source](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/252128)):

```
close(handles.gui)
```